# How to get an mobile app preloaded in android or iphone?

Tags: android, iphone, preload

I am hunting over the web to know **how to preload a mobile application** in both **android and apple iOS** - smartphones and tablets.

Could anyone please let me know the process to get there?

Comment: bribe apple and google? well I can't think of any other option.. BTW is this kind of question is allowed here?

Answer (score -1):

Make your application so beautiful and a must-have so that you get a billion user base. That's it. Then Apple and Google will come to you to preload your application on their mobile platforms :)

Comment: Oh I doubt it.. Do you know any 3rd party application that apple/google preloaded like that? Either they buy the company, or make the app themselves..

Comment: I guess Apple has already tried to include seamless social media experience including Facebook, Twitter in iOS.

Comment: But that is in their framework right? I don't think facebook or twitter app is preloaded with the phone..